# Creating operator= for a library

Tags: c++, class

You have a class libX and you have a class classX. Is there some way to define the assignment function `libX& operator=(const wrapperX&)`?

The obvious way to do it is to modify the .hpp file of the library, but I can't do it. Another way is to wrap my library and define `operator=` for my wrapped function. Does c++ allow a different way to achieve this?

---

Here's the context. Let's say libX in the above example is `boost::multiprecision::number<R>`. And I've a custom class Rational, that has a mpq_t member which is the value. I would like to write things like `number<mpfr_100> val = rationalVal` (rationalVal is my wrapper class.)

Comment: I suggest overloading conversion `operator boost::multiprecision::number<R>` for `class Rational` instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is a clever idea that I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was suggested by @HolyBlackCat in comments.

One can implement the operator `Rational::operator boost::multiprecision::number<T>()` and this would let you cast a Rational into a `number<T>` and then use the `operator=` from boost class for assigning into a boost number.